# Strange error when using Predictive Intelligence tags

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein-recommendations

We began to implement PI this week and I came across this error:

> **ReferenceError**:  SaveAnalyticData is not defined

Which references this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        absoluteBaseUrl = "http://pages.s7.exacttarget.com/";
        SaveAnalyticData(7281803, '1daf6168-ab88-4d85-8fd5-08d6e72d16a2', 'a0459de1-4eed-4843-901b-eafb3272596d'); 
    </script>
```

Anyone know what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My mistake, I had adblock turned on for the website and hadn't noticed it.
I just disabled and it worked fine.